# What does "Exception: unpaired digit" digit mean when trying to use the "assetClassValue" function?

Tags: native-assets

Attempting to use function : assetClassValue (assetClass "67890" "PussToken") 100
Value (Map [(678900,Map [("PussToken",100)])])

Getting error -> Value (Map [(*** Exception: unpaired digit
CallStack (from HasCallStack): error, called at src/Data/Either/Extras.hs:6:34 in plutus-ledger-api-1.0.0.1 a5376ffff9bcd7feae2f904cd9bf193d5371c9e71ecc491aed0dbf5d6852f891:Data.Either.Extras

Answer (score 0):

The input for "assetClass" excepts a paired hex value. I simply turned "67890" into an even number of digits -> 678900.

Then it works-